# Modal showing on page load

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, resize, centering

Hi I've written the following javascript to enable modals with dynamically created id tags to be positioned center screen via a resize function (regardless of their width and height).

However, on page load, the modal is showing, as opposed to having it shown `onClick` via a button. I'm a noob, so I'm not sure what I have to alter in my code so the modal is instead hidden on page load.

Javascript:

```
    $('body').prepend('');

    $(function(){
        $(window).resize(function(){       

    // get the screen height and width  
    var maskHeight = $(window).height();  
    var maskWidth = $(window).width();

    // calculate the values for center alignment
    var dialogTop =  (maskHeight  - $('.modalbox').height())/2;  
    var dialogLeft = (maskWidth - $('.modalbox').width())/2; 

    // assign values to the overlay and dialog box
    $('#overlay').css({ height:maskHeight, width:maskWidth }).show();
    $('#modalcontainer').css({ top: dialogTop, left: dialogLeft}).show();
    }).resize();
    });

    $('a.modal').each(function() {
          var link = $(this);
          var id = link.attr('href');
          var target = $(id);               

          if($("#modalcontainer " + id).length === 0) {
              $('#modalcontainer').append(target);
          }

          $("#main " + id).remove();

          link.click(function() {
            $('#modalcontainer > div').hide();        
            target.show();
            $('#overlay').show();
            return false;
          });
        });

        $('.close').click(function() {
          $('#modalcontainer > div').hide();
          $('#overlay').hide();

          return false;
        });​
```

CSS:

```
    #overlay {
      background: url(../img/overlay_bg.png);
      position:absolute;
      z-index:10;
    }

    #modalcontainer {
    position:absolute;
        z-index:20;
    }
```

HTML:

```
<a href="#modal1" class="modal button plain">view modal</a>
<div style="width:650px; height:400px;" id="modal1" class="modalbox">               
  <div class="box-header">
    <p  align="center">Here is your modal</p>
    <div class="box-content">

    </div>
    <div align="center" class="action_bar">              
      <a href="#" class="close button blue">Close</a>
    </div>
  </div>
    </div>​
```

Demo at jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/5Egf8/4/

Any help is greatly appreciated.?

Comment: If you are using jQuery why not try JQuery UI as well which gives you a ready made jQuery Dialog UI which are highly customizable. check out http://jqueryui.com/demos/dialog/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Update: Now that I can see your Fiddle, I have revised my answer. See the working fork here: http://jsfiddle.net/JXHAt/3/

OK, third time's the charm. I made this much easier by eliminating the #modalcontainer. Instead, to show a `.modalbox`, you just hide the current `.modalbox-active`, then add `.modalbox-active` to the target you want to show.

Comment: Hey, thanks for your reply. I tried adding this to the css, but it didn't help! I'm wondering whether I have to add/remove a .hide() or .show() somewhere?

P.S. Added the HTML and a jsfiddle link too.

Comment: This is great. I will see if I can implement your updates and suggestions into my project. Again. thank you so much. This has drained me over the last few days!

Comment: Hi,

I've been trying to implement your solution within my project, but without much success. I understand the logic put forward in your fiddle, and can see how this works.

But for some reason in my project. clicking the 'view modal' button  open the link in a new page rather than triggering the modal.

Comment: OK. Finally managed to get my modals functioning properly. Thank you again for your help.

Answer (score 1):

Remove the first function() keyword; I don't think you need it:

$('body').prepend('');

```
$(window).resize(function(){       

// get the screen height and width  
var maskHeight = $(window).height();  
var maskWidth = $(window).width();

// calculate the values for center alignment
var dialogTop =  (maskHeight  - $('.modalbox').height())/2;  
var dialogLeft = (maskWidth - $('.modalbox').width())/2; 

// assign values to the overlay and dialog box
$('#overlay').css({ height:maskHeight, width:maskWidth }).show();
$('#modalcontainer').css({ top: dialogTop, left: dialogLeft}).show();
}).resize();
});

$('a.modal').each(function() {
      var link = $(this);
      var id = link.attr('href');
      var target = $(id);               

      if($("#modalcontainer " + id).length === 0) {
          $('#modalcontainer').append(target);
      }

      $("#main " + id).remove();

      link.click(function() {
        $('#modalcontainer > div').hide();        
        target.show();
        $('#overlay').show();
        return false;
      });
    });

    $('.close').click(function() {
      $('#modalcontainer > div').hide();
      $('#overlay').hide();

      return false;
    });​
```

Then make sure all of your () and {} are lining up correctly. Good luck!

Comment: Hi, thanks for the suggestion. You're right. I removed the first function(), and the modal is still centred.

It's still popping up on page load though. If you have any further suggestions I'd be grateful.